# SQL Copy value from relative child cells

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following problem, I can't understand how to copy the values present in the line with level 0.1, in the cells of the relative father with level 0.
I would like to copy the values of Field1 and Field2

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Demo](
    [ID] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [PARENT_ID] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [FIELD1] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [FILED2] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LVL] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Demo]
           ([ID]
           ,[PARENT_ID]
           ,[FIELD1]
           ,[FILED2]
           ,[LVL])
     VALUES
           (''
           ,'1234'
           ,'value01'
           ,'value02'
           ,'0.1')


INSERT INTO [dbo].[Demo]
           ([ID]
           ,[PARENT_ID]
           ,[FIELD1]
           ,[FILED2]
           ,[LVL])
     VALUES
           ('1234'
           ,''
           ,''
           ,''
           ,'0')
```

[image]

Comment: In relational databases there are no "child" cells. All relations are flat and bidirectional. BTW you can avoid using ParentID and storing the level explicitly if you use a [hierarchyid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/lesson-2-creating-and-managing-data-in-a-hierarchical-table?view=sql-server-ver15) field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I probably *wouldn't* copy them, but instead use the parent as a default in a query if the child value doesn't override. To make this easier, I would use NULLs rather than empty strings:

```
SELECT
  p.[ID],
  COALESCE(c.[FIELD1], p.[FIELD1]) as [FIELD1],
  COALESCE(c.[FIELD2], p.[FIELD2]) as [FIELD2],
  p.[LVL]
FROM
  [Demo] p
  INNER JOIN [Demo] c ON c.[PARENT_ID] = p.[ID]
```

COALESCE will, if the child field is null, use the parent field instead. If you are certain you want to keep enpty strings instead of nulls you can create an ANSI compatible query with CASE WHEN:

```
SELECT
  p.[ID],
  CASE WHEN c.[FIELD1] = '' THEN p.[FIELD1] ELSE c.[FIELD1] as [FIELD1],
  CASE WHEN c.[FIELD2] = '' THEN p.[FIELD2] ELSE c.[FIELD2] as [FIELD2],
  p.[LVL]
FROM
  [Demo] p
  INNER JOIN [Demo] c ON c.[PARENT_ID] = p.[ID]
```

But if you really want to copy them you can update a set of tables that are joined:

```
UPDATE c
SET 
  c.[FIELD1] = p.[FIELD1],
  c.[FIELD2] = p.[FIELD2]
FROM
  [Demo] p
  INNER JOIN [Demo] c ON c.[PARENT_ID] = p.[ID]
```

Updating/copying creates a bit of a "have to keep doing it to keep them in sync" problem - realistically it's usually better to have the DB do the join as and when it's needed (it's very fast for a trivial operation like this)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT C.[ID]
      ,C.[PARENT_ID]
      ,ISNULL(NULLIF(P.[FIELD1], ''), C.[FIELD1]) AS [FIELD1]
      ,ISNULL(NULLIF(P.[FILED2], ''), C.[FILED2]) AS [FILED2]
      ,C.[LVL]
FROM [dbo].[Demo] C
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Demo] P
    ON C.[PARENT_ID] = P.[ID];
```

[image]